# Generate JSON from column values in Oracle 12c Enterprise Ed (12.1.0) - 64 Bit

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I have been struggling with an issue in my SQL query. For each record, I have a parent item/record **A** which contains a list of child items/records (**B, C,...**). I can do multiple joins and get the records, but that would duplicate item A (parent item/record) in all the rows. I finally settled on a solution to get the child items/records as JSON arrays for each parent item/record A. That way I will have one parent item in one column and the other columns will have the associated list of child items/records as a JSON array.

I tried using JSON_OBJECT() and other related functions but they don't work on **Oracle 12c R1**. I cannot upgrade my Oracle or install any third-party packages, sadly.

Is there any way to generate JSON without manually creating it?

Much obliged!

Comment: Alas you're out of luck with regards to generating JSON in 12cR1. But reading your first paragraph it seems you **don't specifically need JSON**, it's just something you've hit upon to produce a result set in a certain shape. I suggest you explain more about the actual requirement you're trying to solve - post some sample input data and desired output - and maybe we can suggest a different way of achieving your aim. Include details of the client which will consume and render your query's output.

Comment: ..and if you expect to use  json features,  your management should consider prioritising the upgrade of the software so that their developers could make use of latest technology available. Otherwise switch to a different Open source database that provides you that feature for free.

Comment: I ended up returning the child records as XML instead of JSON.

Comment: @APC Is there a way to return a large `XMLELEMENT` which is in a subquery along with the rest of the select columns?